# Find $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin^{-1}x}{x}$

Tags: limits

Using L'Hopitals rule I have done:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Then diving top and bottom by $x$:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac1x}{\sqrt{\frac1{x^2}-1}}$$
To me this seems to suggest that the limit is zero. However, when I use graphing software to check, it shows that it tends to infinity. What have I done wrong?

Comment: $\arcsin x$ does not makes sense when $x\not\in[-1,1]$. Ditto for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Comment: If complex values are allowed, L'Hôpital is forbidden: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363339/lh%C3%B4pitals-rule-for-vector-valued-functions.

Comment: What can i do instead?

Comment: The limit does not exist because the function is not even defined for large $x$.